# Ports are down for random intervals? (windows & linux)

Tags: php, linux, port, monitor, windows-server

I have a port monitor which queries some server ports to check their status'. Sometimes on the same server (not all or many of them) port 21 is down, however 80 is up. Or port 3001 is down and 443 is working etc.

How could this be possible? Why do the ports sometimes show they are down when they are suppose to be up? Is this a problem? I have several different servers: ubuntu, 2003, centos, 2008 r2, but it occurs on all of them (at random intervals).

Here is my code for the port monitor:

```
function ping($host,$port,$timeout)
{
   $tB=microtime(true); 
   $fP=fSockOpen($host,$port,$errno,$errstr,$timeout); 
   if(!$fP)
       {return "DOWN";}
   $tA=microtime(true);
   return "UP";
}
```

Comment: You are probably running out of resources of some type. It may be sockets system-wide, it may be sockets this process can have, it may be local ports. At least add a call to close `$fP`. How many connections are you trying to open and how quickly are you trying to open them?

Comment: @Bora I'd have to agree with David that your software more than likely isn't reporting correctly. I've never seen ports open and close at random intervals. When a port is open for a specific service, it doesn't temporarily close even when it's not in use.

Comment: @Bora Tagging your question with the correct programming language for your monitor would probably lead to much more help with your problem. It looks like PHP, I'd tag it as such to get the most exposure possible.

Comment: OK, one thing I did notice, you open a socket to your code and never close it, do remember IP limits you to a number of connections at a time. If you have sufficient tests going on it will fail because your machine or the one the other end is not able to create a new conenction for you